# Is it a good practice to always read a value from the object, or store it in a variable and use it?

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to know If it a good practice to always read an value from the object or store it in a variable and use it(why not a good practice or good practise)

Below piece of code

```
private void calc(Product product){
   User = new User(product.getCode(), ...)  // Line 2
   ....
   ....
   if(product.getCode() == 2){ //Line 4
    .....
   }
}
```

At line 2 and 4 , I am getting code from **product.getCode()**. So is it ok to read it from product object or store it in a variable say **String code = product.getCode()** and then use **code** at line 2 and 4

Comment: It depends on how expensive `product.getCode()` is

Comment: `product.getCode() == "2"` is not how you compare Strings

Comment: Looks like `getCode()` is just a getter, in which case you should avoid creating a variable. If it is an expensive operation as Phil commented, like a database or network call or complex logic, you should store it in a variable.

Comment: It’s good style to write the code you find more readable. Which is more readable here depends on a lot of factors. Generally there won’t be any great difference. And when others mention cost: It’s good style to ignore cost until you know you need to take it into account.

Comment: @Kartik what’s the rationale behind your statement “…in which case you should avoid creating a variable”? What’s the advantage of avoiding a local variable?

Comment: I prefer the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle, in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is whether it is good practice to make a local copy of a value or should you always fetch the value from some source that owns the value.

The answer is, it depends.

What you must always remember is that when you are making a local copy of a value from some source, you own a copy of the value. You do not own the value itself nor do you own what ever mechanism is creating the value. You just own a copy. And that copy is a copy of the value generated at the time the copy was made.

So the underlying question is this, when you make a copy of the value, will the generating mechanism you are getting it from change the value it will provide at some time in the future. Should the generating mechanism change the value it generates, your copy of the value becomes invalid.

To answer this question means that you must (1) have some idea as to how the mechanism that generates the value does so and (2) that the generating mechanism will not change at some time in the future in a way that invalidates what you know now regarding how the mechanism generates the value.

Making a local copy of a value from some generating mechanism such as a function will break encapsulation. The generating mechanism and what ever encapsulating and change isolating measures are in place for the generating mechanism are being bypassed and it is no longer the source of the value, the local copy is.

In my opinion the only time any consideration as to making a local copy of a value should be entertained is when the mechanism to get the value is sufficiently costly, usually in terms of time or in terms of computational resources, that it makes sense to have a local copy. Usually the rationale for a local copy is due to the computational cost or the time cost associated with using the generating mechanism. Time costs may be network latency with a server request or if the value takes significant computations to create.

Making a local copy then requires that you ensure that the local copy properly shadows the value that would be provided by the generating mechanism. If the generating mechanism always provides the same value, for instance a function that always provides the same output for the same input, then a local copy is defensible.

If you have some way of monitoring the generating mechanism which provides various values so that the generating mechanism can tell you if there is a new value, for instance a database trigger or some other kind of event, then you can perform that check before using the local copy to determine if the local copy is still valid. If the local copy is no longer valid then you can fetch a new copy using the generating mechanism.

In some cases the time span for how long a local copy shadows the actual value generated falls within the lifetime of the local copy. In other words, the life time of the local copy is shorter than the lifetime of the value generated. For instance a local cache of the value in order to optimize a loop may be appropriate. What I mean by this is that you fetch a copy of the value from the generating mechanism and store that in a local variable, perform a loop which uses the value in a calculation of some kind, and then discard the local copy. This may make the time taken by the loop much less than if fetching the value each time and due to the short time span taken by the loop processing, any changes to the value provided by the generating mechanism is negligible and can be ignored.

An example of this would be to pull the temperature and humidity from a sensor and then perform a series of calculations using just the single value. The reason for doing so is that the overhead of interacting with the sensor and pulling the data is reasonable once but not multiple times within a loop.

Another reason for making a local copy is if there is some kind of noise in the generating mechanism such that the value provided will vary slightly in some range of error. So a sensor may provide a temperature reading that varies slightly each time it is read due to electrical noise in the circuitry so you read the sensor once and then do a number of calculations or process the temperature value in various ways using just the single value in order to reduce the error that comes from multiple, slightly different temperature readings.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the same thing. A String in java is an object, thus when you call `product.getCode()` it will just pass you the reference of that String. But, of course, it depends on what you have behind that method.

BTW, to compare the value of a string you should use:

```
someString.equals(anotherString)
```

To compare the reference you should use:

```
someString == anotherString
```

Answer (score 0):

We can compare those different approaches basing on the following three criteria.

1. Performance: in this case they should be the same, unless product.getCode() is expensive.
2. Cleanness: if you call product.getCode() multiple times, the second approach will be cleaner.
3. Space: the second approach has to use auxiliary space.

Answer (score -1):

If it is something simple and cheap, then I would keep reading it from the object. I would separate it into its own variable if it makes the code more clear or easier to understand.